# ASP.NET MVC5 Set post number when writing a post on one or more posts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I made a total of three bulletin boards. 
There is one table in the DB.
I want to give each post a unique number for the post. 
I want to do this one time on the bulletin board.
However, my bulletin board has 1 bulletin board 1,2
I go up to number two on bulletin board 3,4. Please tell me how to fix it.

1 bulletin board

```
   @{
     int i = 0;
     int idx = 0;
    }
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

     idx = Model.Count - i;
     String str = "Notice";
     if (@item.Category.Equals(str))
      {
       <tr>
       <td>@idx.ToString()</td>
       <td>@item.Category</td>
       <td><a href="/Board/Edit?aidx=@item.ArticleIDX">@item.Title</a></td>
       <td>@item.ModifyMemberID</td>                                   
       <td>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.ModifyDate).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")</td>
       </tr>
     }
   i++;
 }
```

2 bulletin board

```
   @{
     int i = 0;
     int idx = 0;
    }
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

     idx = Model.Count - i;
     String str = "FAQ";
     if (@item.Category.Equals(str))
      {
       <tr>
       <td>@idx.ToString()</td>
       <td>@item.Category</td>
       <td><a href="/Board/Edit?aidx=@item.ArticleIDX">@item.Title</a></td>
       <td>@item.ModifyMemberID</td>                                   
       <td>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.ModifyDate).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")</td>
       </tr>
     }
   i++;
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx9IC.jpg)

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. Are your referring to the `idx` value? And what are you expecting to output?

Comment: I want to print this. For example, I think there are announcements and bulletin boards. If the article is posted on the bulletin board, it is correct to go up to 1, 2, 3 times, 1, 2, 3 times when the bulletin board goes up. But I am going to go to the bulletin board 3 times and 4 times on the bulletin board once.

Comment: Sorry, you last comment is just as unclear as your question

Comment: I put the image in the body. I want to make a bulletin board like the image.

Comment: If its `idx` your referring to (you still have not confirmed that) then you not de-incrementing the value - just use `@{ idx = Model.Count; }` and in the loop, delete `idx = Model.Count - i;` and add `@idx--` after the `</tr>`.

Comment: And its just `<td>@idx.</td>` - you do not need `.ToString()` - everything in html is just text.

Comment: I did what you told me.
It does not stop.

Comment: Does not stop what?

Comment: Translator error.
It does not work.

Comment: What are you talking about? Perhaps you need to ask someone with a reasonable grasp of English to help you ask the question

Comment: I did what you told me, but it does not come with the image.

Comment: If i am not wrong according to your question & comments you are looking unique number for 3,2,1(bullets)?